# How do I generate an ELF file given custom C/C++ code to override default provided .elf file in an existing project?

Tags: c++, sdk, elf, vivado, microblaze

I have been trying to determine if I can generate an ELF (Executable Linkable Format) using SDK tools in Xilinx Vivado 2018.3 for generation of instruction memory content.   Nowhere do I see a simple procedure for generating such a file (updated to match cpp sources modified after acquisition of a project using Microblaze and HDL Code, along with CPP source files.

Any help in generation of ELF files in the mentioned toolset would be appreciated.

Comment: Apparently, after trying again with "Create new Application Project", and then opened a new C++ empty project in a new workspace, I then imported in code into src directory, I renamed main.cpp to main.cc and built all.  The new file was successfully generated.